# ChildProcessCrashException in Dagster multiprocess execution in multi-container Docker deployment

Tags: python, dagster

I have a Dagster job that is training a CNN (using Keras). The Op that runs `fit()` is causing the following error:

```
Multiprocess executor: child process for step train unexpectedly exited with code -9
dagster.core.executor.child_process_executor.ChildProcessCrashException

Stack Trace:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagster/core/executor/multiprocess.py", line 163, in execute
    event_or_none = next(step_iter)
,  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagster/core/executor/multiprocess.py", line 268, in execute_step_out_of_process
    for ret in execute_child_process_command(command):
,  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagster/core/executor/child_process_executor.py", line 157, in execute_child_process_command
    raise ChildProcessCrashException(exit_code=process.exitcode)
```

No additional output is given. I am using a multi-container local Docker deployment.

Things tried:

- I run the code locally (non-Docker) by using `execute_in_process()` and this works without error.
- Due to the mention of executor and multiprocess in the stack trace I tried setting the `execution` to `in_process` but this merely hangs.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Caused by memory issues and solved by increasing the memory settings in Docker.

Comment: What memory did you increase? RAM, Virtual Memory, SWAP? Asking for those of us who do not run dagster in docker containers - (virtual machines etc) and experience this issue.

Comment: Docker's settings has a "memory" setting which I increased to 16Gb. I'm not sure what this refers to under the hood but it is separate from the swap memory setting.

Answer (score 0):

It's RAM Related. As the guy said, he just needed to reconfigure docker to use more RAM, in his case, about 16GB RAM. I had the same issue and also on Openshift and using a POD. So if anyone else had the same problem, just try increasing your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is searching for answers, I was able to fix this by increasing the `runCoordinator` resources:

```
          runCoordinator:
            enabled: true
            type: QueuedRunCoordinator
            config:
              queuedRunCoordinator:
                maxConcurrentRuns: 2
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: 100m
                  memory: 4Gi
                requests:
                  memory: 4Gi
```